# python 2.7 split unicode text using unicode comma

Tags: python, unicode, split

I have a unicode string (种类：猫; means type:cat）which contains a unicode colon ': ' in Chinese. I would like to separate the string into 2 parts using:
`a.split(u': ')`

The length of the result list is always 1, so not spliced.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do this type of operation? Thanks!

Comment: `u': '` <- that's an ascii colon followed by a space. Try splitting on `u'：'` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a FULLWIDTH COLON, not an ASCII colon:

```
>>> s = u'种类：猫'
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> for c in s:
...     print hex(ord(c)),ud.name(c)
...     
0x79cd CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-79CD
0x7c7b CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-7C7B
0xff1a FULLWIDTH COLON
0x732b CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-732B
```

So you can split it a number of ways:

```
>>> s.split(u'\uff1a') # by Unicode codepoint
[u'\u79cd\u7c7b', u'\u732b']
>>> s.split(u'\N{FULLWIDTH COLON}') # by name
[u'\u79cd\u7c7b', u'\u732b']
>>> s.split(u'：') # Using the correct (single) character
[u'\u79cd\u7c7b', u'\u732b']
```

Since you are using Python 2.7, to see the output correctly you'll need to print the list items:

```
>>> for item in s.split(u'\uff1a'):
...     print item
...     
种类
猫
```

Comment: Many thanks, this solved my problem. And gives me a way to find out the unicode representation of specific characters .